# How can I modify only a part of "query" in URL?

Tags: perl, url, mojolicious

I have a Mojo app. And I have a list of URLs from "a" tags. I want to *either* add some query params to each one or modify existing query params in it if they already exist in that URL. The rest of a URL must remain untouched.
Here's how I'm doing it:

```
  $doc->find('a')->each(sub {
    my $aTag = $_;
    my $aUrl = Mojo::URL->new($aTag->attr('href'));
    my $newUrl = $aUrl->query->merge('q_key1' => 'something', 'q_key2' => 'something2'); # <--- warn: returns only the query part, removes the "path" part
    $_->attr('href' => $newUrl->to_string);
  });
```

The problem is that it returns only the query part and removes, for instance, the "path" part when it exists.

Whereas I want all of it as is: path, domain, proto, etc... -- I only want to add/modify the query part and only "q_key1" and "q_key1" params.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you call `->merge` on the Mojo::Parameters object that `->query` returns explicitly you only get the query part of the URL. Get rid of the `->merge` and [use an array reference](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL#query) instead, and it will return the URL object.

> Query part of this URL, key/value pairs in an array reference will be merged with "merge" in Mojo::Parameters, and key/value pairs in a hash reference appended with "append" in Mojo::Parameters, defaults to a Mojo::Parameters object.

This does what you want.

```
use Mojo::URL;

my $url = Mojo::URL->new('http://example.org/foo?bar=test&q_key1=asdf');
my $new_url = $url->query( 
    [ 
        'q_key1' => 'something',
        'q_key2' => 'something2',
    ]
);
say $new_url->to_string;
```

Output:

```
http://example.org/foo?bar=test&q_key1=something&q_key2=something2
```

Note that this is not a copy, but the same object with updated values. You don't need to assign it to a `$new_url`.